# M-Audio Oxygen v4 49 Disconnection Problem

Tags: recording, midi, electronic-music, midi-controller-keyboard

1. Using Windows 8.1 x64
2. Using POD X3 Live as a soundcard (which is working fine and not disconnecting during my guitar recording sessions)
3. I'm using ableton lite x64
4. Both my POD X3 Live and Oxygen is being connected to my computer with USB 3.0 Connection (My motherboard doesn't have and USB 2.0 ports)
5. Using ASIO driver for POD X3 Live
6. My ableton lite is a registered product.

During recording sessions, while playing/recording with ableton samples the connection between my computer and Oxygen 49 v4, **voice is cut off and doesn't solve until i restart M-audio Oxygen 49 v4 hardware**

**Here's what i checked so far :**
1. Nothing abnormal with POD X3 drivers, they're all up to date with line 6 monkey, even the pod x3 product software.
2. Installed and upgraded pod x3 drivers for windows 8.1 x64
3. When the voice cuts off, i am able to see voice data is flowing through usb, i can see that from ableton mixer.
4. Updated my motherboard drivers from the product website.

How can i fix this random voice mute problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution :

1. Open Control Panel
2. Go to: Hardware and Sound->Power Options
3. Find your preferred power plan and click “Change plan settings”
4. Click “Change advanced power settings”
5. A dialog box similar to the example in the graphic below will open
6. Find the entry “USB settings” and expand it
7. Expand the entry “USB selective suspend setting”
8. Use the drop-down menu and change it to **disabled**

No device disable during recording / playing with samples anymore.

Works perfectly !